# Exception while accessing Repository.GetElementSet in Enterprise Architect

Tags: sql, vba, enterprise-architect

I tried to automate the traceability between the elements in Enterprise Architect using VBA scripting. If the traceability already existed between the elements I need to skip those elements.

I wrote using one simple query where the Object ids are present in the EAP.

```
   set useCaseCollection = Repository.GetElementSet("select Start_Object_ID from t_connector where (Start_Object_ID = -1222814411  and End_Object_ID = 505879126 and Connector_Type = 'Realisation')",2)
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
   Session.Output( useCaseCollection.Count)
   End if 
   On Error Goto 0
```

Now the problem is I am getting one exception as **Item not found in the collection** if the traceability exists between the elements. If traceability is not there then it's printing the value as zero. Anything is wrong in the above approach or any other solution is there for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer is simple. `GetElementSet` only works on `t_object` (Elements) not on `t_connector`. Use `SQLQuery` instead. Or use a `JOIN` to actually return the connected element, rather than the object ID.

Something along those lines:

```
dim useCaseCollection as EA.Collection
set useCaseCollection = Repository.GetElementSet("select * from t_object WHERE object_ID in (SELECT start_object_id FROM t_connector)",2)      
Session.Output( useCaseCollection.Count)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be enough to change the alias of the field `Start_Object_ID` in your query to read `Object_ID`

```
set useCaseCollection = Repository.GetElementSet("select Start_Object_ID as Object_ID from t_connector where (Start_Object_ID = -1222814411  and End_Object_ID = 505879126 and Connector_Type = 'Realisation')",2)
```

Assuming of course the rest of the query is OK; I've never seen negative object ID's.

Comment: thanks, the alias is working. But my doubt is the alias is shorthand of column name, Start_Object_ID and Object_ID both return the same value.So GetElementSet is searching for "Object_ID", not its type or value.I also never seen negative object ID's, I taught it may be EA feature.

Comment: Yes I suspect that EA checks looks in the resultset from the query for a column named "Object_ID". Everything else is probably ignored.